# How to test a Saga with an API call?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, redux-saga

I have a saga

```
export function* mysaga(api, action) {
  const response = yield call(api.service, action);
  yield put(NavActions.goTo('Page', { success: response.ok }));
}
```

That calls an API and with return value navigate to another screen passing the API call result (`response.ok`).

```
it('test', () => {
  // ...

  const gen = mysaga(api, action);
  const step = () => gen.next().value;

  // doesn't actually run the api
  const response = call(api.service, {});

  expect(step()).toMatchObject(response); // ok

  // error, Cannot read property 'ok' of undefined
  expect(step()).toMatchObject(
    put(NavActions.goTo('Page', { success: response.ok }))
  );
});
```

Since it's not actually running the API call `response` doesn't get defined.

I don't know what I should do to test this scenario.

How do I test the second step of my saga?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the yield expression resolves to whatever it yielded. However, you can pass another value to the gen.next method and then the yield expression is resolved to what you passed there.

So this should do the trick (untested):

```
const gen = rootSaga(api, action);
const step = (val) => gen.next(val).value;

const mockResponse = { ok: true };
const response = call(api.service, {});

expect(step(mockResponse)).toMatchObject(response); // ok

expect(step()).toMatchObject(
  put(NavActions.goTo('Page', { success: true }))
);
```